# Prevent scrapy from removing square and curly braces from url

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I need to pass a nested dict as parameter to a get request.

Here is how it should look to work

```
query = {%22channel%22:%22rent%22,%22page%22:2,%22pageSize%22:12,%22filters%22:{%22agencyIds%22:[%22CBPHMG%22]}}
```

Here is what I get in Scrapy logs:

```
%7B%22pageSize%22:%20300,%20%22page%22:%208,%20%22channel%22:%20%22rent%22,%20%22filters%22:%20%7B%22agencyIds%22:%20%22VDTUED%22%7D%7D
```

The problem is with square and curly braces.

What I do now is just `json.dumps(dict)` and append it to url. I also tried to use backslash to prevent from changing the symbols. No avile.

```
 q = {"channel":"sold","page":1,"pageSize":300,"filters":{"agencyIds":["PRDNEW"]}}
 query = json.dumps(q)
 query = query.replace('"', '\\"')
 url = url + query
```

Also the following code works fine with python3 requests.

```
import requests

url = "https://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search"

querystring = {"query":"{\"channel\":\"buy\",\"page\":2,\"pageSize\":12,\"filters\":{\"agencyIds\":[\"CBPHMG\"]}}"}

headers = {'cache-control': 'no-cache'}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `w3lib.url.add_or_replace_parameter` to append the `query` parameter to the URL. It will URL-encode the same way as python-requests:

```
$ scrapy shell
2017-07-18 11:03:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
>>> url = "https://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search"
>>> querystring = {"query":"{\"channel\":\"buy\",\"page\":2,\"pageSize\":12,\"filters\":{\"agencyIds\":[\"CBPHMG\"]}}"}
```

This is the same input data as your `python-requests` example.

Use [`add_or_replace_parameter`](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.add_or_replace_parameter) with the name of the parameter and its value (note: Scrapy already depends on w3lib.):

```
>>> from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameter
>>> add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'query', querystring['query'])
'https://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search?query=%7B%22channel%22%3A%22buy%22%2C%22page%22%3A2%2C%22pageSize%22%3A12%2C%22filters%22%3A%7B%22agencyIds%22%3A%5B%22CBPHMG%22%5D%7D%7D'
```

Here, in Scrapy shell, fetching the new URL will get a JSON response back, as expected:

```
>>> new_url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'query', querystring['query'])
>>> fetch(new_url)
2017-07-18 11:04:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-07-18 11:04:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search?query=%7B%22channel%22%3A%22buy%22%2C%22page%22%3A2%2C%22pageSize%22%3A12%2C%22filters%22%3A%7B%22agencyIds%22%3A%5B%22CBPHMG%22%5D%7D%7D> (referer: None)


>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads(response.text)
>>> data.keys()
dict_keys(['prettyUrl', 'totalResultsCount', 'resolvedQuery', '_links', 'tieredResults', 'channel'])

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
{'_links': {'adCall': {'href': 'https://sasinator.realestate.com.au/rea/hserver/site=rea/area=buy.resultslist/proptype=villa/constructionStatus=established/sub=marsden/state=qld/pcode=4132/region=logan/price=200k_300k/platform={platform}/version={version}/pos={position}/size={size}/viewid={viewId}/random={random}',
                       'templated': True},
            'canonical': {'href': 'http://www.realestate.com.au/buy/by-cbphmg/list-2'},
            'exclusiveShowcaseUrl': {'href': 'https://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/exclusiveShowcase?query=%7B%22propertyTypes%22:[],%22atlasIds%22:[],%22channel%22:%22buy%22%7D'},
            'neighbourhoodsUrl': {'href': 'http://www.realestate.com.au/neighbourhoods?state=qld'},
            'next': {},
            'ofi': {'href': 'https://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/ofi/{date}/daytotals?query=%7B%22channel%22:%22buy%22,%22pageSize%22:%2212%22,%22page%22:%222%22,%22filters%22:%7B%22agencyIds%22:%5B%22CBPHMG%22%5D%7D%7D',
                    'templated': True},
            'prettyUrl': {'href': '/buy/by-cbphmg/list-2'},
            'saveSearchUrl': {'href': 'https://www.realestate.com.au/saved-searches/#/save?search=%7B%22channel%22:%22buy%22,%22pageSize%22:%2212%22,%22page%22:%222%22,%22filters%22:%7B%22agencyIds%22:%5B%22CBPHMG%22%5D%7D%7D'},
            'self': {'href': 'https://services.realestate.com.au/services/listings/search?query=%7B%22channel%22:%22buy%22,%22pageSize%22:%2212%22,%22page%22:%222%22,%22filters%22:%7B%22agencyIds%22:%5B%22CBPHMG%22%5D%7D%7D'}},
 'channel': 'buy',
 'prettyUrl': '/buy/by-cbphmg/list-2',
 'resolvedQuery': {'channel': 'buy',
                   'filters': {'agencyIds': ['CBPHMG']},
                   'page': '2',
                   'pageSize': '12'},
 'tieredResults': [{'count': 11,
                    'results': [{...}],
                    'tier': 1}],
 'totalResultsCount': 23}
```